# how to automatically assign a value to a cell depending on the value entered in a previous cell

Tags: excel, formula

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 31 |
| 1-5 | 32 |
| 6-10 | 34 |
| 11-15 | 35 |

I have created a drop-down menu for people to select a value between 0 and 15. In another cell I would like to automatically assign the corresponding value of column B. could someone help me please with the formula - many thx

I tried various suggestions for IF function but I am not sure about the formulae

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the entire ranges of numbers. Just their minimum value. Like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 31 |
| 1 | 32 |
| 6 | 34 |
| 11 | 35 |

Then use a formula like:

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(C2,A2:A5,1))
```

where C2 is the cell in which the value selected in the drop-down is reported.

*Note: the MATCH function as used in the formula needs the data to be stored in ascending order. More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).*

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn’t really work. 
I have created the following table in a separate worksheet called ‘list items’: A.     B
0 31
1 32
6 34
11 35


On another worksheet in cells D4 I have a drop down menu to select the number between 0-38. This should then lead to an automatic assignment in cell D5 to the corresponding value.

Comment: I don't follow. In your question you talked about a drop-down ranging from 0 to 15. Now the drop-down ranges from 0 to 38? Isn't column B the output and column A the filter? What's exaclty your goal?